# 5 entries per page on blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/whatever is too low

Tags: discussion, user-experience, blog

Links like https://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/company/ show only 5 entries per page, with ton of whitespace below last entry (due to long list of tags on the right). This is especially bad on pages for tags with entries without images: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/podcasts/. Having so short pages is inconvenient. Can we have longer pages?

Comment: It seems, something was done about it?..